# can't send a picture file to backend using formData and axios post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux, multer

i have a MERN stack application , i want to submit a form containing an file input and normal text inputs , the submitted form is sent to a redux action and inside the action i'm using formData to transform the image to binary form and send it to the backend using formData.append and axios .post  and in the backend i got the usual multer code with upload.single('photo') . the backend by itself works i tested it with postman . 
FRONT-END REDUX ACTION :

```
// update user info
export const updateUser = (userData, id) => dispatch => {
    var form = new FormData()
    console.log(userData.photo);
    if (userData.photo) {
        form.append('photo', userData.photo);

    }
    axios
        .post("http://localhost:4000/api/users/update/" + id, userData)
        .then(res => {
            axios
                .post('http://localhost:4000/api/users/upload_photo/' + id, form)
                .then(res => {
                    const { user } = res.data;
                    console.log(user);
                    //save new user to localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
                    //dispatch to reducer
                    dispatch({
                        type: UPDATE_USER,
                        payload: user
                    })
                })



        })

}
```

BACKEND API

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/user');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, req.params.id + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + file.originalname);
    }
});
let upload = multer({ storage: storage })
//profile picture upload 
router.route('/upload_photo/:id').post(upload.single('photo'), function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send("user is not found");
        }
        else {
            user.photo = {};
            user.photo.path = req.file.path;
            user.save().then(() => {
                res.json({ message: 'picture uploaded!', user: user });
            })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).send("Upload not possible");
                });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Could you provide more infos? Are you receiving any error or is it not working as expected?

Comment: yes am recieving an error from the '.post('http://localhost:4000/api/users/upload_photo/' + id, form)'  the backend isn't getting the expected file the req.file is empty so the problem is with 'form' object that am passing with the post request and its from formData